# is there any temporary table after query?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

After I got results from some query is there any name of temporary table created from those results???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you can easily create a temporary table from the results of a select statement:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptablename AS
SELECT ...;
```

Then to get the result:

```
SELECT * FROM temptablename;
```

Comment: yea yea...i know what to do..after I do all steps I have to, just to DROP this table...this sql query I am goint to execute by php and then use pgsql2shp also in php.
ok, now is everything clear in my head:)

Comment: You don't have to drop the table - because it is created as temporary it is dropped automatically when the connection is closed.

Comment: aaa, ok:) that great than, one row less:)))

Comment: Caveat: temporary tables are usually for interactive use; to use them in a web application, for example, is a dubious practice IMO.

Comment: Yes. The intention is to be used for web application.